# git-tfs ignores changes to config

Tags: tfs, checkin, git-tfs

I used git-tfs with TFS2012 for a while, but recently we migrated to TFS2013 and the TFS address has changed.

I can't seem to do `git tfs checkin` any more as it tries to send changes to the old address.

I updated the url in `.git\config` , cleared TFS cache, but git-tfs still tries to checkin using the old address and appends new `tfs-remote` with the old url to the config file every time I try to do it.

How can I make it to checkin to the new url?

Comment: Should probably have used `git tfs configure` to update instead.

Comment: I'd simply clone a new local repository from the TFS server if I were you :).

Comment: As the command does stuff on the TFS side as well (create workspace, map folders etc).

Answer (score 0):

To make checkin with a new TFS address use an ability to set up it explicitly via checkin options:

```
-i, --tfs-remote, --remote, --id=VALUE
                         The remote ID of the TFS to interact with
                         default: default
```

Also it is recomendet to clean git and git-tfs cache by next commands accordingly:

```
git gc
git tfs cleanup
```